# Ruby Mongo - Get back ID after insert

Tags: ruby, mongodb

For example:

```
result = collection.insert_one({ name: 'test' })
```

Now how do I get back the ID of the new document, assuming it was successfully inserted? Is there any way to get it from `result`? Seems to be possible with some languages/drivers but can't see how to do it with [default Ruby Mongo driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver), unless I ran a query afterwards.

Comment: Are  you use https://github.com/mongoid/moped?

Comment: Just the default/official driver. I linked it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first generate the id and then send the insert with the id included.

```
oid = BSON::ObjectId.new
result = collection.insert_one({ _id: oid, name: 'test'})
```

This way you have all the info already and don't need to get anything back.

Comment: That's a good decision, since Mongo doesn't return anything after insert.

Comment: Agree it works, thanks. Would still like to know if there's any way to be lazy and let the server return it.

Comment: @mahemoff: nope, I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

```
oid = result.inserted_id
```

plz refer to [official docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/Mongo%2FOperation%2FWrite%2FInsert%2FResult:inserted_id)